# Using part of a large WinForms project inside a large WPF project

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, winforms-interop

Both of these applications are rather old and have been built and maintained over several years by several people. At the moment, one of controls used in the WinForms project really needs to be displayed in the WPF project.

I've read about using WinForms controls in WPF projects, and for the most part if you're just instantiating a regular empty WinForm control, it seems relatively simple.

What I'm wondering is how you would best approach using part of a large project in another project? Ideally the WinForm control will be visible from within ONE of our WPF controls, on ONE tab, after having been sent and loaded the required data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some general guidelines.

From your WPF application, add project references to:

- your WinForms project
- `WindowsFormsIntegration`
- `System.Windows.Forms`

Modify your XAML to include a [`WindowsFormsHost`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.windowsformshost(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <TabControl>
            <TabItem Header="Old Form">
                <WindowsFormsHost Name="WinFormsHost"></WindowsFormsHost>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Instantiate your old `Form` and set it as the child of the `WindowsFormsHost`. Set `TopLevel` to `false` or it'll complain that "the child control cannot be a top-level form." Change the `FormBorderStyle` too, to prevent the Form's title bar from showing up and allowing the user to drag the Form around.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    WinFormsHost.Child =
        new Form1 { TopLevel = false, FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None };
}
```

You end up with something like this:

[image]

You can read more in "[Walkthrough: Hosting a Windows Forms Control in WPF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751761(v=vs.110).aspx)" and the MSDN documentation for the "[WindowsFormsHost Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.windowsformshost(v=vs.110).aspx)".

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at those resources. I was just somewhat concerned because the WinForms project has so many libraries and classes and different projects inside it, that I wasn't sure that just slapping the entire massive project into the WPF project would work. We'll see how it goes.